# .NET "Appcmd migrate config" fails with "user name or password incorrect"

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-2.0, iis-8.5, appcmd

I tried to run this from the command prompt (run as administrator):
appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site/"

I get this error:
ERROR ( hresult:8007052e, message:Command execution failed.
The user name or password is incorrect.
 )

The error code hresult:8007052e means incorrect user name or password.

The rest of the story:
I'm trying to migrate a web site where the code for one application is accessed via shared folder on another server. So, credentials are required to access this application's code.  I think Appcmd needs these credentials to do its job.

By the way, this web site configuration works; it's in production. But the application uses .NET Framework 2.0, and I want to migrate it to .NET Framework 4.x.  I have successfully migrated this web site code in my dev and test environments, although all their code is on the same server and they don't use credentialed access.

Is there a way to specify user name and password as part of a call to Appcmd?  Is this migration even possible?  Is there another way to do this migration?

Comment: If you want to move a site from one server to another, Microsoft only gives an option to use Web Deploy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-web-deploy/synchronize-iis

Comment: Not moving website. Migrating (converting) web configuration from old .NET Framework 2.0 to new Framework 4.0.

Comment: So what login user are you using for appcmd and share folder? I made some test on my local and it seems that appcmd migrate config is executed as your system user. So it seems didn't return any error when I use domain administrator account. It also seems work when I create the user  with same name and password on both IIS server and share folder server. It looks like we need special permission to access redirection.config.

Answer (score -1):

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD.exe set vdir /vdir.name:"Default Web Site/MyApp1/" /userName:"mydomain\myuser" /password:"myp@$$word"